# How to debug an aspx page, keeps saying page not found when there is an error

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging, webforms

I have a page with a listview and there is some problem with it, however instead of getting an error, when I run it I get a 404 resource not found error. If I remove the offending listview and run then it runs fine, so it is not an issue with it not looking in the right place for the page etc.
How can I find out what the error is with the listview, at the moment I'm getting no information about it, it even renders correctly in design view.

Many thanks

For info the code is below, however I need to know how to debug it as this has happened lots of times before.

If I remove this listview the page works..

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvPerformanceKPIs" runat="server"
         OnItemDataBound="lvPerformanceKPIs_ItemDataBound" DataKeyNames="PerformanceMeasureID" 
        OnItemCommand="lvPerformanceKPIs_ItemCommand" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder"
        >
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"> 
                <tr>
                    <th width="5%" class="Actions" >
                        Actions
                    </th>
                    <th width="2%" >&nbsp
                    </th>
                    <th width="5%">
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th width="28%">
                        Group
                    </th>
                    <th width="40%">
                        Indicator
                    </th>
                    <th width="20%">
                        Threshold
                    </th>                        
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div runat="server" id="itemPlaceHolder">
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div id="Div1" class="SUBDIV" runat="server">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%" class="Actions">
                            <%--<img id="btnEdit" style="cursor: pointer;" alt="Edit" title="Edit this record" src="images/edit.png" width="15px" 
                                onclick="CRMEdit(this);"/>             

                            <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" title="Delete this record" src="images/delete.png" width="15px"
                                 OnclientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?')" 
                                 CommandName="cmdDelete" CommandArgument=<%#Eval("PerformanceMeasureID") %>  />   --%>
                        </td>
                        <td width="2%">
                            <div class="btncolexp collapse" title="Expand to reveal/add files">
                                &nbsp;
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <!-- id columns to get values then will be hidden with jquery -->
                        <td class="hidCol">
                            <span id="itemServiceSpecID"><%#Eval("ServiceSpecID")%></span>
                        </td>
                         <td class="hidCol">
                            <span id="itemPerfSortOrder"><%#Eval("PerfSortOrder")%></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="hidCol">
                            <span id="itemPerfType"><%#Eval("PerfType")%></span>
                        </td>
                        <td class="hidCol">
                            <span id="itemPerfFrequency"><%#Eval("PerfFrequency")%></span>
                        </td>
                        <td width="5%">
                            <span id="itemPerformanceMeasureID"><%#Eval("PerformanceMeasureID")%></span>&nbsp
                        </td>
                        <td width="28%">
                            <span id="itemPerfGroup"><%#Eval("PerfGroup")%></span>&nbsp
                        </td>
                        <td width="40%">
                            <span id="itemPerfMeasure"><%#Eval("PerfMeasure")%></span>&nbsp
                        </td>
                        <td width="20%">
                            <span id="itemPerfThresholdText"><%#Eval("PerfThresholdText")%></span>&nbsp
                        </td>
                    </tr>          
                </table>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: use  F12 of youre browser when getting the error

Comment: That just debugs the "Server Error in '/' Application." page.

Comment: can you show some code / more info

Comment: I can, but the issue is I need to be able to debug the page as this has happened on numerous occasions, it seems when there is a problem with the aspx page it just isn't compiled (or whatever) and it cant be found. But there is no indication of what the error is. I will edit the question with the listview though...

Comment: try to identify the problem to its core, so that is is in smallest form :) as small as possible, remove rows, remove header.. etc

Comment: If you put a break point on the very first line of `page_load`, does it reach there?

Comment: Thanks for your help, in the end I switched back to an earlier version and redid the work and it works ok now. It's a shame there's no better debugging functionality though, surely if it can't render the page for whatever reason it should know at about what point it was that it couldn't render, but what do I know.

Answer (score 0):

i wonder if those images are properly commented-out in the item template. make sure there is no conflict between the comment tags (<%-- --%>) and the data binding tags.

also, the CommandArgument needs to be quoted:

```
CommandArgument='<%#Eval("PerformanceMeasureID") %>'
```